# Embed JSF code in a xhtml

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to complete a xhtml page with some JSF code (with p:panel and p:datatables, etc.) from a managed bean, but I'm not sure that is possible.
My attemps:

1º

```
<h:outputText escape="true" value="#{controller.jsfString}"/>
```

It's not be able to understand "p:" components, only simple html.

2º

```
<ui:include src="#{controller.jsfString}">
```

It expects a xhtml path, not a String.

I don't know what else try... Is it even possible?

Comment: I have the feeling you are trying to reinvent the wheel and you're actually looking to make a custom/composite component that you can reuse. http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: The mykong reading is very interesting (thx @Gimby), but unfortunately It's not what I'm looking for. I just need to build a String in my controller with some jsf code and then put this jsf code in my page within the rest of the jsf code... I'd prefer use invented wheels, promise!

Comment: Well zim's answer of "no" gets my upvote then. Could you at least provide context WHY you must do it the not-JSF way? Are you fetching the page content from a database or something?

Comment: There are definitely ways depending on concrete functional requirement. For example, JSF is able to resolve Facelets templates from any resource, such as a DB as hinted by @Gimby. [You'd better elaborate the concrete functional requirement in detail rather than asking how to achieve a completely wrong solution to that requirement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This attempt is based on a fundamental thinking mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's not be able to understand "p:" components, only simple html.

Of course it is not!
The `h:outputText` value is evaluated at view render time, so if you render JSF tags, they won't be evaluated again since rendering is done.

In principle, it could have been possible to add JSF tags this way using the JSTL `<c:out>`, but it is not available in JSF facelets.
Anyway, just tell yourself that it prevents you from making bad design.

We'll need more information regarding what the controller is supposed to output in order to help you.

Comment: Just knowing that It's not possible you helped me enough. @Gimby I wanted to get the jsf code from a controller because the complexity of the logic I have to implement was too much (mixed datatables from database entities and so on), but I will try. Thank you all!

Answer (score -2):

Here p means prime-faces u need to include prime-faces dependency in pom and enable tag lib for prime-faces in XHTML then u can use the all the prime-faces components.

Comment: I am using primefaces components in my page, so my jsfString also has primefaces components, but the primefaces components in jsfString are not being interpreted.